# Bootstrap Dropdown disabled after installing Bootstrap RTL when TextInfo.IsRightToLeft

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

ASPNET MVC5 website, Visual Studio 2015

There's really nothing special in following dropdown:

```
       <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/Categories">Manage Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="/RolesAdmin">Manage Roles</a></li>
                <li><a href="/UsersAdmin">Manage Users</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/Gifts/PendingApproval">Pending approval</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

and it's working as expected until a "right-to-left" culture is chosen, firing related .js and .css to load, after having installed Twitter Bootstrap RTL v. 3.0 package:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-rtl").Include(
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-rtl.js",
        "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css-rtl").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap-rtl.css",
        "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Choosing such a language (Arabic for instance), RTL versions are loaded

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css" + (CultureHelper.IsRighToLeft() ? "-rtl" : ""))
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap" + (CultureHelper.IsRighToLeft() ? "-rtl" : ""))
```

somewhat interfering with any dropdown, preventing them from working (i.e. clicking on "Admin" nothing happens). Changing back to any ltr language makes dropdowns work again.